# If $0 < p < 1$, then does $\int_{0}^{p}\frac{1}{x^p}dx =-\frac{1}{(p-1)(p^{p-1})}$.

Tags: calculus, integration

If $0 < p < 1$, then does $\int_{0}^{p}\frac{1}{x^p}dx =-\frac{1}{(p-1)(p^{p-1})}$ For example, if $p=0.5$ then $\int_{0}^{0.5}\frac{1}{x^{0.5}}dx =-\frac{1}{(0.5-1)({0.5}^{0.5-1})}$. I know $\int_{0}^{p}\frac{1}{x^p}dx = \frac{1}{1-p}$, but it's impossible to make this into the $-\frac{1}{(p-1)(p^{p-1})}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because of the formula (valid for any $p\ne 1$)
$$\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{x^p}=-\frac 1{(p-1)x^{p-1}}\qquad({}+C),$$
so that
$$\int_0^p\frac{\mathrm dx}{x^p}=-\frac 1{(p-1)x^{p-1}}\biggr\vert_{0}^p$$
Observe that the function in the r.h.s. is defined for $x=0$ and is equal to $0$, since $p-1<0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{0}^p \frac{1}{x^p} \ dx = \frac{x^{-p+1}}{-p+1}\Big]^{x=p}_{x=0}=\frac{p^{1-p}}{1-p}=\frac{1}{(1-p)p^{p-1}}$$